# Tensorflow in Python

Tags: python, tensorflow

While training tensorflow in python, the program gets killed after sometime. There is nothing getting printed in the logs as error or warning.

I am using Fedora24, Python 2.7 and Tensorflow 0.12

This is the link of the code I tried. https://github.com/inikdom/neural-sentiment/blob/master/train.py

The output is as follows:

python train.py
No hyper parameter changed detected, using old checkpoint...
vocab mapping found...
Creating model with...
Number of hidden layers: 2
Number of units per layer: 50
Dropout: 0.5
Vocab size is: 20002
['data2.npy', 'data3.npy', 'data0.npy', 'data1.npy']
Number of training examples per batch: 200,
Number of batches per epoch: 250
Created model with fresh parameters.
Beggining training...
Maximum number of epochs to train for: 50
Batch size: 200
Starting learning rate: 0.01
Learning rate decay factor: 0.97
Test size is: 14800, splitting into 74 batches
Killed

I do not know if this is caused by the session.run method. I cannot avoid that method as well. Please help..

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Its because of memory usage. Just increase the memory, if you are using a VM.

Answer (score 0):

May be buffer memory got increased if you are doing more cleanups and function. You can clean the buffer memory using the below garbage collection function. Also, you can add gc.collect() wherever required in the program. It will clear your unwanted buffer memory.

```
 import gc

 gc.collect()
```

Also, del variable and list if process is over or unwanted.